# Delete duplicated data text that is not exactly the same but is similar

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a data frame and I need to detelete duplicated data. My main problem is that some data is duplicated but the text is not excactly the same.

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 234 | ALEJANDRA AZYADtETH ONTIVEROS CABALLERO |
| 235 | ALEJANDRA CABALLERO |
| 236 | ALEJANDRA ONTIVEROS CABALLERO |
| 237 | 10119715 - TIUSA |
| 238 | 10119715 -TIUSA |
| 239 | 10118580 - BAEZ |
| 240 | 10118580 â€“ BAEZ |

I want to get a more homogeneous data frame. I already use duplicate() so the data that is exactly the same is gone.

Here are two samples of the data.

```
carrier_data1 <-
  structure(list(
    Id = c(
      2784L,
      2639L,
      6499L,
      6917L,
      6922L,
      1060L,
      6920L,
      13847L,
      5792L,
      5705L,
      4229L,
      7196L,
      6916L,
      5767L,
      5675L,
      5644L,
      9808L,
      5756L,
      7669L,
      3030L
    ),
    Name = c(
      " ALEJANDRA AZYADtETH ONTIVEROS CABALLERO",
      " ALEJANDRA CABALLERO",
      " ALEJANDRA ONTIVEROS CABALLERO",
      " ANTONIO MARQUEZ JUAREZ",
      " ARACELI NAVARRETE GONZALEZ",
      " ARELLANO VALDEZ LUIS EDUARDO",
      " AUTO EXPRESS DAMAJA",
      " AUTOTRANSPORTES PRIMAVERA",
      " BODEGUITA",
      " BUTRON GARCIA RAFAEL",
      " CALDERON HERNANDEZ JAIME",
      " CISNEROS QUEZADA JOSE HILARIO",
      " CYCA",
      " DANIEL QUIROZ PINEDA",
      " DRIVER",
      " DYLKA DISTRIB. Y LOGISTI K",
      " ERIK VELAZQUEZ MENA",
      " EVOLUTION",
      " FAVELA VELAZQUEZ MARIO",
      " FRANCISCO RICARDO MARTINEZ HERNANDEZ"
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,
                20L),
  class = "data.frame")
```

```
carrier_data2 <- structure(list(
  Id = c(
    7709L,
    7714L,
    7717L,
    7708L,
    7723L,
    7707L,
    7753L,
    7754L,
    7743L,
    8721L,
    7727L,
    8667L,
    7724L,
    8496L,
    8443L,
    7702L,
    7751L,
    7742L,
    7711L,
    7744L,
    8735L,
    7755L,
    7349L,
    7757L,
    7759L,
    10249L,
    10250L,
    9932L,
    9341L,
    10432L,
    10292L,
    10424L,
    9518L,
    12120L,
    10337L,
    3568L,
    7148L,
    3196L,
    9403L,
    13150L,
    11925L
  ),
  Name = c(
    "10113183 - TRANSVETA",
    "10114582 - KARGOFER",
    "10118580 - BAEZ",
    "10118580 – BAEZ",
    "10119715 - TIUSA",
    "10119715 -TIUSA",
    "10123682 - HUGO ACUÑA SOSA",
    "10123781 - EDUARDO ACUÑA",
    "10125173 - TRANAN",
    "10130382 - GENOVEVA",
    "10133499 - TRABAL",
    "20-20",
    "24-7 TRANSPORTES INTERNACIONALES",
    "3 GENERACIONES KRONOS",
    "3 PL",
    "3 RS",
    "3 T CARRIER",
    "3CG GROUP",
    "3G-S",
    "3PL CARGO",
    "3R DE MEXICO",
    "3T",
    "4 ANTHAGO",
    "4 CAMINOS",
    "4 KARDO",
    "495TRANSPORTES TRAZIL",
    "4-A TRANSPORTES",
    "4GA",
    "501 RT",
    "501 TR",
    "5pl",
    "7 SEVEN",
    "7Jr6SRQW#",
    "99 MINUTOS",
    "A",
    "A & E EXPRESS",
    "A A TRUCKING",
    "A RAPIDOS LOZANO",
    "A TEMPORE",
    "A&R",
    "A1A TRUCKING"
  )
),
row.names = 166:206,
class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: please share your data with dput

Comment: is this really the final, tidy version of the data.frame? 10....TIUSA and Alejandra.... do not seem to reflect the same type of data, but are all in the `name` column

Comment: Now i got the dput. Yes it seems like a diferent category but this is how i get the database.